# Tensorflow JS: inference and training=true equivalent

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, inference

I'm trying things with the Pix2Pix model as presented in Tensorflow tutorials.
So I wrote the model in Python then I converted it to javascript.

The problem is, on inference, I need to take the training route for some layers and in tf python, it's easy, I just pass training=true on inference:

```
output=model(input, training=true)
```

But how do I do that "training=true" in javascript inference with my converted json model?

```
const output = model.predict(input); //training=true???
```

Is there a model paremeter or another function to do that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @tempapy, Could you give more context on your inquiry? Do you intend to retrain the created model in javascript?

Comment: @TF_Support, I have a similar question and problem as well. Having Dropout or Batch Normalization in the model requires `training = True` in Python. However, after loading the model in Java, I do not how to `feed` or here to feed training = True in Java.

Comment: And here is my question on GitHub as well for more details. (1) tensorflow/java, https://github.com/tensorflow/java/issues/284, (2) tensorflow/tensorflow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48643